# Vulkan performance issues if data is sorted

Tags: performance, sorting, buffer, vulkan

I am rendering a grass field. Each grass blade xz-position is stored in an instanced vertex buffer.

I was generating this positions using a halton sequence, hence the positions within this buffer were "random". Later on, I decided to generate them using chunks as Z-curves to improve data locality and prepare to implement frustum culling.
Even without frustum culling implemented yet, performance improved, but only while looking at a specific direction (while the opposite direction actually got worse).

To make sure I wasn't going insane, I went back to the old branch which used the halton sequence to generate points and sorted them. This are the results:

| Sort by | Look at -x | Look at x | Look at -z | Look at z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| none | ~25 FPS | ~25 FPS | ~25 FPS | ~25 FPS |
| `a.x < b.x` | ~15 FPS | ~30 FPS | ~20 FPS | ~20 FPS |
| `a.x > b.x` | ~30 FPS | ~15 FPS | ~20 FPS | ~20 FPS |
| `a.z < b.z` | ~20 FPS | ~20 FPS | ~15 FPS | ~30 FPS |
| `a.z > b.z` | ~20 FPS | ~20 FPS | ~30 FPS | ~15 FPS |

This is running on Intel graphics (mesa). It might also be worth mentioning that I'm using
[Vulkan Memory Allocator](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/VulkanMemoryAllocator).

Going back to the Z-curve implementation and adding frustum culling such that only the positions of the blades within the frustum are written to the buffer changed nothing. Furthermore, shuffling the blades "fixed" the issue, going back to a stable (but lower) FPS.

I also want to make clear that I'm not doing any conditional work based on the value of the view matrix (unless frustum culling is enabled), just the usual matrix/vector multiplication.

What could be causing all this?

Comment: Guessing that when the closer blades are rendered first, they occlude the further blades earlier since they write their closer depth value sooner. If the further blades are rendered first, the closer blades will then will not similarly occluded and will have to be drawn on top.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Seems like you're correct: if I disable depth testing the FPS are stable, but the scene is not properly rendered (obviously), just some part of it. But how to deal with this? Should I sort the positions by distance to camera? I thought the point of depth testing was to avoid this.

Comment: Depth testing will get you a scene that looks OK, but it has performance implications. Each fragment that you render only to have something else rendered on top of it is wasted work (unless you're blending). If the GPU knows the fragment will never pass the depth test, it can skip running the fragment shader, so getting the closest depth object is helpful to reduce overfill. You can potentially look into sorting, or [doing a z-prepass where you render just the depth first](https://interplayoflight.wordpress.com/2020/12/21/to-z-prepass-or-not-to-z-prepass/). There may be other techniques too.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Sorting works (stable 35 FPS), but a z-prepass seems like a better idea, I will look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard quirk of early depth testing (and other such tests such as hier-z). If you draw front-to-back so that the closest grass to the camera is drawn first, then later blades can be proven to be occluded and can be thrown away early.

Most GPUs also have some standard form of hidden-surface removal which doesn't rely on front-to-back render, but these schemes all have their quirks and will be less reliable than early-depth tests.

I would suggest coarsely sorting grass batches rather than individual blades - the sort won't be free on the CPU. However, it's unlikely you would need to fully resort every frame unless your camera is jumping around, which helps.

Comment: Sorting works. With frustum culling, even sorting per-blade each frame is considerably better than before. I will look into implementing a z-prepass as suggested by ColonelThirtyTwo and see what works best. Thank you.

Comment: Are your grass shaders using alpha testing / `discard`?

Comment: Im not using `discard` nor doing alpha testing (should I ?)

Comment: Not necessarily - but be aware that that also has an effect on vendor hidden-surface removal schemes.